# My LSL particles won't go away even though I've deleted the script. How can I turn them off?

Tags: linden-scripting-language

If you have a script that creates a particle system and then delete the script from the prim, the particles don't seem to go away.  How can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because particles are considered a property of a prim, much like its textures.  Therefore, you must add a script to the prim that clears its particle settings:

```
default
{
    state_entry()
    {
        llParticleSystem([]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Evil Spork's answer is fine. I'd just recommend removing the script when you're done. Because as he said particles are a prim property and you **only need the script to change** the particle settings.

This is why I'd rather use:

```
default
{
    state_entry()
    {
        llParticleSystem([]); // or llLinkParticleSystem(LINK_SET, []); for whole object
        llRemoveInventory(llGetScriptName()); // remove the script, we don't need it anymore
    }
}
```